Power automate excel to html table, select return null value
I am trying to create an html table in power autmate from an excel table and latter attach the html table to the body of an e-mail
But the 'Select' output return null values even when input has values. As result the table is created empty
The map value is items('Apply_to_each_2')?['Pay responsible users']
 
I Would like the select output to return the values

make it without whitespace characters in the Select action Map section
